# How to create a Service with ROSJava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you install latest release of ROSJava you have an example named: rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.
This example is really useful to understand how to publish topcs and how to subscribe, but in the release, I didn't have any example to create a service with rosjava.

Anybody can help me?

Juan Antonio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12494/how-to-create-a-service-with-rosjava/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2012-01-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Services are also created from nodes just as publishers and subscribers are. Have a look at the javadoc for Node.newServiceClient and Node.newServiceServer.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2